# Option tags not showing up when generated by PHP

Tags: php, html, firefox, html-select

I'm currently working on a calendar website, and one of its functionalities is that administrators should be able to create reservations for other people. To try and re-use webpages, I want to do this dynamically; if they are administrators, a select box should appear, and otherwise the user's own name should appear as a static bit of text.

To do so, I've written the following PHP snippet:

```php
<?php

// Be sure that we included the msql lib
include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/assets/php/intern/msql.php");

if ($user_info["admin"]) {
    // If the user is an administrator, then show the picker

    // First, get a list of all (possible) users
    $users = msql_fetch(msql_start(), "SELECT * FROM users WHERE role <= ?",
                        $user_info["role"]);
    if (count($users) == 0) {
        // That's weird; should be at least the logged-in user
        echo("<span style='color: #FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;'>Error; herlaad de pagina</span>");
    } else {
        // Generate a list of options from this list
        $options = "";
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            // Typify that user
            $user = typify_user($user);

            // Generate the option
            $options = $options . "<option value=\"" . $user["id"] . "\"";
            // If this is the present user (which is guaranteed to exist, I'd say), then set it as default
            if ($user["id"] === $user_info["id"]) {
                $options = $options . " selected";
            }
            $options = $options . ">" . $user["name"] . "</option>";
        }

        // Generate the actual div
        echo(
            "<select id=\"home-create-reservation-name\" style=\"padding: 5px;color: #22CC00;font-weight: bold;\">" .
            $options .
            "</select>"
        );
    }
} else {
    // Otherwise, show the user's name statically
    echo("<span id='home-create-reservation-name' style='color: #22CC00;font-weight: bold;'>" . $user_info["name"] . "</span>");
}

?>
```

The snippet seems to work, as it successfully generates a select element if the user is an administrator, or a static name span if the user isn't.

However, the issue I'm having is that the option-elements are somehow not added properly, and instead the select box appears empty:

[empty select box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnNoA.png)

To add to the mystery, this is the code that Firefox' inspector shows:

```html
<select id="home-create-reservation-name" style="padding: 5px;color: #22CC00;font-weight: bold;">webmaster</select>
```

But the raw source content that Firefox receives is:

```html
<select id="home-create-reservation-name" style="padding: 5px;color: #22CC00;font-weight: bold;"><option value="1" selected>webmaster</option><option value="17">lut_99</option><option value="19">dummy</option></select>
```

And in fact, if I copy/paste this as the HTML content of the same select in the inspector, then suddenly the select behaves properly and shows all three user accounts.

I should note, though, that because I'm using Firefox and this page is only accessible when logged in, I can't use 'view source' directly but instead copy the response of the first HTTP request made by Firefox. I *think* this shouldn't be an issue, but please, let me know if it is.

I have the feeling I'm making a very simple and stupid mistake, but I just can't find out what it is. Adding a 'name' attribute doesn't help either, nor changing the HTML quotes to single quotes in the PHP snippet.

Can anyone see what is going wrong here? Do let me know if you require extra information.

Thanks!

Comment: _“I should note, though, that because I'm using Firefox and this page is only accessible when logged in, I can't use 'view source' directly”_ - why not, what is your login based on then?

Comment: _If_ the browser actually received proper HTML code to begin with - then maybe something else is messing with your select field afterwards, some JavaScript perhaps …?

Comment: I can't use the view source because for me, the view source doesn't seem to send cookies like the PHPSESSION cookie. In any case, the webserver redirects me to the login page - and that's the HTML I see instead.

Comment: Also, you are my hero - I had a look over my Javascript, and found that there was indeed an old line from when I used to load this in Javascript that sets the element's text to the username... \*facepalm\* Thanks a lot!

EDIT: As far as I understand it, I can only mark actuals answers as answer - so if you do that, I can mark your reply as such :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I changed it to match my own site's rules and I saw that you are using a `mysql_fetch()`. First of all, it should be `mysqli_fetch()`, or `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`. However, the main problem here is that you are searching for a single user. `mysqli_fetch()` doesn't return the entire query (you could have used `var_dump($reply)` or `print_r($reply)` to find out). You should use a while loop with a query variable instead:

```
$q = $db -> query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE role <= ?" . $user_info["role"]);
while ($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
    //Do the select and options stuff here
}
```

I tried this on my own site and there was no longer a problem. Just, the `<select>` thing took a bit to load (I don't know why, but this happened only once).

So, what exactly does this do? This while loop fetches the query once every time. The `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` function returns only the first row if used once. If you use it again, later, it returns the next row. I hope I've helped and I am usually online to answer possible questions (about any more complex things).

Comment: Sorry, I get the confusion, but I wrote my own wrappers around PDO and called it msql_fetch() etc to avoid typing a lot :) The mysql functions are thus not the problem. The actual problem was already discussed in the comments and solved - but I can't mark that as an answer... Thanks for your suggestion, though!